# Trying to scrape a learning management site using BeautifulSoup and Requests

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

so I have some python code here that is supposed to go to a learning management site, specifically the calendar, and then find all of the tasks under the current day and print them off. However, I keep on getting this error at line 5:

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

This is only my second time doing BeautifulSoup and Requests, and I've googled this error, but I haven't found any fixes that pertain to my code. Thanks in advance for the help!

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
website = requests.get('https://gatech.instructure.com/calendar').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(website, 'lxml')
first_table = soup.find("table")[1]
big_body = first_table.find("tbody", {'class': 'fc-body'})
x = int(input("What week of the month?"))
week_div = big_body.find('div', {'class': 'fc-row fc-week fc-widget-content'})[x]
week_table = week_div.find('table')[1]
current_day = week_table.find('td', attrs={'bgcolor': '#f5f5f5'})[2]
assignments = current_day.find('a', {'class': 'fc-day-grid-event'})
Data = []
for assignment in assignments:
    Data.append(assignment.get('title'))

print(Data)
```

Comment: You would need to signin to `gatech` website for this

Comment: Ah, I should of added to the post that I am already signed in automatically.

Comment: If you signin you would need to give the cookies and all.. It's better you go with `selenium`

Comment: I've never used selenium. I would really appreciate if you could help me get started (and explain what it does compared to requests)!

Comment: @ScottJanssen selenium can be used to automate a real webbrowser. You can load webpages including dynamic content and enter text into input fields (like your login). It is heavily used by developers to implement automatic tests for webpages. It is also frequently used for webscraping - but typically unnecessary. All you need to do in your case is create a requests session, and send a simple post request to https://login.gatech.edu/cas/login. The session will take care of all cookies and you might add an attribute to your header. Do you need help with that?

Comment: @Gregor I can probably manage, but I'll let you know if I need any help. The only thing that troubles me is that I have two factor authentication enabled, so I'm not sure how to get around that.

Comment: @Gregor Second thought, I would love some help since I can't figure it out for the life of me

Comment: @ScottJanssen You won't be able to bypass the two factor authentication (because that's what it's designed for). Unless Georgia Tech provides an API that you can use to login neither BeautifulSoup nor Selenium will work.